# CS193P Smashtag Popularity Extra Task #3 - Get only new tweets using "IN" keyword

Tags: swift, cs193p

I'm working on Stanford CS193p's SmashTag Popularity Mentions assignment (asst. #5) and I've got everything working well. I'm working on Extra Task #3:

*Loading up a lot of data by querying for an existing instance in the database, then inserting if not found over and over again, one by one (like we did in lecture), can be pretty poor performing. Enhance your application to make this more efficient by checking for the existence of a pile of things you want to be in the database in one query (then only creating the ones that don’t exist). The predicate operator IN might be of value here.*

I've managed to do something *like* this, but not using the `IN` predicate operator! This is inside the `perform` block of my `updateDatabase(with newTweets:)` method: (I've called my core data entity  `CDTweet`

```
if let databaseTweets = try? globalContext!.fetch(NSFetchRequest<CDTweet>(entityName: "CDTweet")) {
            let databaseIDs = databaseTweets.map { $0.id! }
            for twitterInfo in newTweets where !databaseIDs.contains(twitterInfo.id) {
                _ = CDTweet.createCDTweet(with: twitterInfo, into: globalContext!)
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I get all the tweets in the database, get their IDs, and then only create a new tweet for internet-fetched-`Twitter.Tweet`s whose IDs are not in the array of database tweets.

This appears to function properly (i.e., create only the new tweets), but I am very curious how the instructor imagined it would work with the `IN` predicate operator. Has anyone done this and can lend some insight?

Note: A number of solutions I've seen have a core data entity for the Search Term (usually called Query). I don't have this, only entities for Tweet and Mention, and I have everything working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this (i assume `searchIDs` is an array of values you are looking for):

```
var searchIDs = // ... an array of IDs you are searching for
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<CDTweet>(entityName: "CDTweet")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", searchIDs)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
databaseTweets = try? globalContext!.fetch(fetchRequest) {
     // here you should only get all entries with IDs in the newTweets array
}
```

Details about predicates can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate), about predicate syntax especially [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789)

Comment: But if the idea is to find only new tweets from the database, don't those tweets need to be in the database already? So you'd have to run your tweet-entity-creator function (tweetForTweetWithTwitterInfo in the lecture) on all downloaded tweets, and then search the new database for tweets matching the downloaded ones. If the point is to only run the creator function for new tweets, this is too much work. Am I missing something here?